# Dynamically determine Structuremap dependency

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, structuremap

I have a service interface, IService, that has multiple implementations which retrieves data from different data sources. In my WebApi controller, I want this dependency to be resolved during runtime, based on a boolean flag that is set in BaseApiController by a custom action filter:

```
public class BaseApiController : ApiController
{
    // Set during runtime by a custom action filter
    public bool Condition { get; set; }
}

public class MyController : BaseApiController
{
    private readonly IService _service;

    public MyController(IService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }
```

I want to be able to configure my StructureMap container such that it checks the condition in the base controller, and creates a concrete implementation of IService accordingly.

I'm looking for some kind of lambda that can be evaluated at runtime. I've tried ConditionalUse(), but it doesn't feel like the correct approach, since it seems to be invoked when building the container and not at runtime.

Comment: What does this `bool Condition` represent and when and by whom is it set?

Comment: You can always define a factory method for instantiation in which you can check arbitrary runtime state. The state certainly can't come from the controller, considering that you are in the middle of calling its constructor...

Comment: It indicates whether to use a fake data source. It is set in a custom action filter that runs for each request.

Comment: @flq: yes, I might have to change where I store the state, didn't think of that... Could you provide an example of the factory method that you mentioned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `Use` overload that allows you to specify a Factory-Method. E.g. in a registry:

```
bool isTest = true;
For<IServiceProvider>().Use(
     ctx => isTest ? (IServiceProvider)ctx.GetInstance<Foo>() :
                     ctx.GetInstance<Bar>())
```

If you have multiple implementations, you could also consider having two different registries and use the `IncludeRegistry` to determine which one to use at runtime.